# Derivative of a differentiable stationary Gaussian process

Tags: st.statistics, stochastic-processes

Thanks for your help in advance.  I'm interested in understanding the properties of derivatives of a differentiable stationary Gaussian process.  Specifically, is the derivative also a Gaussian process?

Comment: What's an example of a differentiable stationary Gaussian process?

Comment: But, limits of Gaussians are Gaussian, so the answer must be yes.

Comment: I suppose an example would be a point rotating about the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ started with a symmetric normal distribution.

Comment: I apologize if I mis-stated the question -- I'm still learning about this area.  Specifically, consider a 1D signal f(x) generated by some stationary stochastic process for which the distribution of f(x) is Gaussian, and (say) the autocorrelation is also Gaussian.  What can be said about the distribution of values of f'(x)?  

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes in the sense that the gradient of the mean is a GP defined jointly with the original GP.   I'm sure it's discussed elsewhere, but you can find derivations in section 5 of 
http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~sudiptob/ResearchPapers/BGjasa06.pdf.

Comment: the link is no longer valid. From the URL, I am guessing it was a preprint version of this paper (sec 2 instead of 5??):
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/016214506000000041

Banerjee, S., & Gelfand, A. E. (2006). Bayesian Wombling: Curvilinear Gradient Assessment Under Spatial Process Models. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 101(476), 1487–1501.

Answer (score 0):

[Malliavin calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malliavin_calculus) is the apropriate framework for your question
Take $F \in \mathscr S$ (the space  of  functions such that all  derivatives are of polynomial growth).

We define
$$
 DF = \sum_i  \partial_i f ( W(h_1), \dots,  W(h_n) ) h_i,
$$
and this should be regarded as an $H=L^2$-valued r.v.

$D$ is well-defined. In particular for $F=W(h)=\int_0^1 h_t d B_t$ this is a consequence of the Ito-isometry.